# How to fix the exception "org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Buffer overread by 4 bytes"

Tags: java

I used omctraceidl-0.1.jar in my code and an exception was thrown:
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Buffer overread by 4 bytes. I've never seen this error before. Can anyone help me?

```
try {
    traceServiceITF.getTaskById(securityToken, ossTaskId, taskHolder);
    return taskHolder;
} catch (WarningMsg e) {
    logger.error("queryTaskById get WarningMsg");
} catch (ErrorMsg e) {
    logger.error("queryTaskById get ErrorMsg");
} catch (FatalErrorMsg e) {
    logger.error("queryTaskById get FatalErrorMsg");
} catch (SM_INVALID_TOKEN e) {
    logger.error("queryTaskById get SM_INVALID_TOKEN");
}
```

Expected result: No exception thrown
Here is the log:

```
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Buffer overread by 4 bytes
    at org.openorb.io.AbstractInputStream.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.openorb.iiop.CDRInputStream.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at org.openorb.iiop.CDRInputStream.read_ulong(Unknown Source)
    at org.openorb.iiop.CDRInputStream.read_wstring(Unknown Source)
    at imap.TraceService.TraceTask_THelper.read(Unknown Source)
    at imap.TraceService._TraceService_ITFStub.getTaskById(Unknown Source)
```